# Spring Hibernate MySQL Query acos() error

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I am working on a small Spring Boot project which uses Hibernate. One of my repository methods should return list of teachers in given radius. However, when I tried to accomplish this with a query (note that I am totally new to SQL) my `acos()` function gives this error.
Here is my query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT teacher FROM teacher WHERE " +
            "acos(sin(radians(latitude)) * sin(radians(lat))" +
            "+ cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(lat))" +
            "*cos(radians(lng)) - radians(longitude))" +
            "*3959 <= distance")
    Iterable<Teacher> findTeachersAround(@Param("latitude") double latitude, @Param("longitude") double longitude, @Param("distance") double distance);
```

In this query when I bring mouse to acos(), I get followed error message:

> expression, operator, GROUP, ORDER or HAVING expected, got '('

I tried simply writing a number inside closure, still got the same error.

Comment: Do not use images. Paste your code here. Also, your SQL query is not clear. It looks error is pasted in the query only

Comment: You should avoid at any cost use hard-coded SQL queries. In fact, you must model your database using Hibernate annotations and use Spring Boot queries based on method names (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods)